# Why is my vectorized Numpy code taking longer than the non-vectorized code

Tags: python, performance, loops, data-science, vectorization

So I am calculating Poisson distributions using large amounts of data. I have an array of shape (2666667,19) - "spikes", and an array of shape (19,100) - "placefields". I used to have a for loop that iterated through the 2666667 dimension, which took around 60 seconds to complete. Then, I learned that If I vectorize for loops, it becomes much faster, so I tried to do so. The vectorized form works and outputs the same results, however, now it takes 120 seconds :/

Here is the original loop (60s):

```
def compute_probability(spikes,placefields):
    nTimeBins = len(spikes[0])
    probability = np.empty((nTimeBins, 99)) #empty probability matrix
    for i in range(nTimeBins):
        nspikes = np.tile(spikes[:,i],(99))
        nspikes = np.swapaxes(nspikes,0,1)
        maxL = stats.poisson.pmf(nspikes,placefields)
        maxL = maxL.prod(axis=0)
        probability[i,:] = maxL
    return probability
```

And here is the vectorised form (120s)

```
def compute_probability(spikes,placefields):  

    placefields = np.reshape(placefields,(19,99,1))
    #prepared placefields

    nspikes = np.tile(spikes, (99,1,1))
    nspikes = np.swapaxes(nspikes,0,1)
    #prepared nspikes

    probability = stats.poisson.pmf(nspikes,placefields)
    probability = np.swapaxes(probability.prod(axis=0),0,1)
    return probability
```

Why is it SO SLOW. I think it might be that the tiled arrays created by the vectorized form are so gigantic they take up a huge amount of memory. How can I make it go faster?
download samplespikes and sampleplacefields (as suggested by the comments)- https://mega.nz/file/lpRF1IKI#YHq1HtkZ9EzYvaUdlrMtBwMg-0KEwmhFMYswxpaozXc

EDIT:
The issue was that although it was vectorized, the huge array was taking up too much RAM. I have split the calculation into chunks, and it does better now:

```
placefields = np.reshape(placefields,(len(placefields),99,1))
nspikes = np.swapaxes(np.tile(spikes, (xybins,1,1)),0,1)
probability = np.empty((len(spikes[0]), xybins))

chunks = len(spikes[0])//20
n = int(len(spikes[0])/chunks)
for i in range(0,len(nspikes[0][0]),n):
    nspikes_chunk = nspikes[:,:,i:i+n]
    probability_chunk = stats.poisson.pmf(nspikes_chunk,placefields)
    probability_chunk = np.swapaxes(probability_chunk.prod(axis=0),0,1)
    if len(probability_chunk)<(len(spikes)//chunks):
        probability[i:] = probability_chunk
    else:
        probability[i:i+len(probability_chunk)] = probability_chunk
```

Comment: You should provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  For instance, current code missing function definition (just a return), spikes, placefields, etc.

Comment: I see. I added a download link to randomized sample data, as well as function definitions

Comment: If removing the for loop didn't speed up the process then it probably means the for loop is not the constraint. As an initial diagnosis step, try [profiling the code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to find out what steps are using most of the computation time.

Comment: In trying to run compute_probability using input from your link I get **ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1881 into shape (19,100,1)** for line `placefields = np.reshape(placefields,(19,100,1))`.  Issue is placefields has shape (19, 99) after np.load(...).  Also: why do you have arguments data and session_number if they are not used in the functions.

Comment: whoops, I meant np.reshape(placefields,(19,99,1)), sorry. I have those arguments because I forgot to remove them from this post. Originally I have them in there due to the sturtucre of the original data. The sample data and placefields are one of the sessions, randomly shuffled

Comment: @AlexMarkov--issue with iterative version (first function).  Error **AxisError: axis2: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1**.  Error occurs on first iteration (i = 0) and is on line `nspikes = np.swapaxes(nspikes,0,1)`.  spikes has shape 19, 266663) and nspikes has shape (1881,).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to **memory/cache effects**.

The first code work on small arrays fitting in the CPU caches. It is not great because each Numpy function call take some time. The second code fix that issue. However, it allocate/fill **huge arrays** in memory of several GiB. It is much faster to work in CPU caches than in main memory (RAM). This is especially true when the working arrays are used only once (because of expensive OS *page-faults*) which seems to be the case in your code. If you do not have enough memory, the OS will read/write temporary data in SSD/HDD storage devices that are very slow compared to the RAM and the CPU caches.

The best solution is probably to work on chunks so that the operation is both vectorized (reducing the overhead of the Numpy function calls) and fit in CPU caches (reducing the cost of RAM reads/writes). Note that the size of the last level cache is typically few MiB nowadays on mainstream PC processors.

The takeaway message is that vectorization do not always make things faster. For better performance, one should care about the size of the manipulated data chunks so they fit in CPU caches.

PS: note that if you do not care too much about precision, you can use simple-precision (`np.float32`) instead of double-precision (`np.float64`) to speed up a bit the computation.

Comment: I see, thank you. I will now attempt to split the huge array into smaller pieces and operate on those. How do I know how much memory is being taken up, and how do I know what size chunks would fit in CPU caches?

Comment: You can do that analytically. The amount for memory used for an array is `np.prod(arr.shape)*arr.dtype.itemsize`. You can also check the memory usage consumption of the whole process using profiling tools or OS tools (CPU monitoring). Measuring the throughput of the RAM vs caches experimentally is is much harder to do. You can use low-level profiling tools such as Perf (Linux) and Vtune (Windows/Linux) to check hardware counters.

Comment: For the cache size this is dependent of your CPU. You can use the hw-loc tool to retrieve this information. However, generally only the LL cache matters for such kind of computation. Thus, it is good to try to keep the sum of the computed chunks per iteration smaller than 1-2 MiB if possible, since almost all mainstream CPU have at least few MiB of LL cache (and the CPU/OS/libs do not use it perfectly). Using double-precision, this means about 128K scalar values (spread in several different arrays).

Comment: I followed your suggestion, and split the calculation into chunks. It is not faster than it was in the original loop